# Fixing linking errors

Tags: c++, error-handling

This is my function declaration. I get a unresolved external error using Visual Studio 2010 C++.

```
    bool CheckCrcByte(const CHAR_t* pbData, UINT32_t lLength, UINT32_t lMsgCrc) 
   { 
       bool FlagPass;
       UINT32_t lCalcCrc;
       UINT32_t lInitCrc = 0;
       lCalcCrc = ~lInitCrc; 
       CHAR_t* bCurrent = (CHAR_t*) pbData;
       while (lLength-- > 0) 
       {
         lCalcCrc = (lCalcCrc >> 8) ^ crc_TABEL[(lCalcCrc & 0xFF) ^ *bCurrent++];
       } 
       lCalcCrc = ~lCalcCrc;
       if (lMsgCrc == lCalcCrc)
       {
          FlagPass = true;
       } 
       else
       { 
          FlagPass = false;
       }
       return FlagPass; 
     }
```

Comment: You've declared CheckCrcByte (or you included a header that declares it, but didn't link against it.  Is that your function or did it come from a library you're linking against?

Comment: I wrote CheckCrcByte myself and declared it in CRC32.cpp which is included in the code I wish to integrate it with (#include "CRC32.h")

Comment: Ok, I notice that your function is defined "__cdecl", is it possible you built it with a C compiler rather than C++, but are calling it from C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you have declared the function:

```
bool CheckCrcByte(char const *,unsigned int,unsigned int);
```

But you have not defined it. To define it, do the following in a `.cpp` file:

```
bool CheckCrcByte(char const * c,unsigned int i1,unsigned int i2)
{
    //Your function code goes here.
}
```

Always make sure your function prototype for your declaration matches the definition for its identifier and parameter types.

In the following code:

```
bool CheckCrcByte(const CHAR_t* pbData, UINT32_t lLength, UINT32_t lMsgCrc)
{
//YOUR TYPES ARE NOT THE SAME THEREFORE IT IS A DIFFERENT FUNCTION DEFINITION
}
```

By what you told me you defined in the comments, you have defined the second function but you need to define the first as well. They are two different functions.

Comment: You need to match the function prototype with its definition. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: Then you are calling the wrong one. It says the linker problem is with  the first one you posted. This means that this one doesn't have a definition.

Comment: @user2633955 Literally copy and paste the function definition above and then get back to me. (The first definition, not the second)

Comment: The problem was that the cpp and h file wsan't added to the project through the IDE although they were in the correct folders. Thank you for all the responses. you helped me alot!